# Can I get a Log of all ASP.net Control Events fired by my page even if I don't handle those events?

Tags: asp.net, logging, webforms, trace

I have an asp.net page with several controls (ListViews, Buttons etc).

I'd like to generate a log (possibly outputted to the Trace log) of all:

1. events were caused by the user on postback (e.g. Clicks, SelectedIndexChanging, etc)
2. events that were not caused by the user, but are fired by each control no matter what (e.g. init) or due to programmatic action (e.g an ItemDataBound event for a ListView caused by programmatic databinding).

Even if I don't specifically handle the ItemDataBound event for a ListView for instance, i'd like to see a log entry showing that it fired.

I know this could be a very very long list (i.e. each control fires many events and there are many controls per page), but still would like to see it if possible.

I would like this for informational and possibly for debugging purposes so I can see what each control is doing. It might also give me an idea for an event to handle. I know the API docs in theory provide this info, but i'd like an interactive log specific to my ASP.net page.

Answer (score 0):

Have you explored ASP.NET's tracing functionality?  This sounds very similar to what you want. An overview is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386420%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

You have the option of looking at trace data at the bottom of a page, or in a separate trace viewer.  You can also access it programmatically.

Now, this is only going to list events that fire:  in general, the way most ASP.NET web controls are written, if there is no handler for an event, the code doesn't raise it.  So you will probably only see events that are being handled.

Comment: Thanks, I know a bit about tracing.  From what I can tell you have to manually use Trace.Warn in each event handler for each event i would want to log , is that right? I wanted to get that functionality automatically. Also want to somehow get every control's Init event (just for example) even if I don't handle or every SelectedIndexChanging even if I don't handle it (say i forgot), but I guess you're saying that may be impossible if I don't have a handler for it.

Comment: Disclaimer:  I'm not an expert, as I've never tried to do what you're trying to do.  But it occurs to me that Microsoft's EntLib Unity framework, which allows policy injection, might help you out.  Here's an article:  http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2009/01/31/unity-and-aop-in-enterprise-library/